# Buttons under listview in android application

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I need to have buttons appear below a listview. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I've tried different ways to get this specific layout to appear correctly on android, but so far I haven't been able to figure this out. I want to be able to display a listview in the middle of the app and have buttons under the listview. The problem is that I have other things that need to be displayed on the screen on top of the listview such as tabs and spinners. All of the items in the listview will have both an image and some text to the right of the image. The image that I'd like to achieve is like this image...

[android layout image](http://movieinsanity.com/img/layout_pic1.jpg)

Here's my code so far...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:maxLines="100"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/readWebpage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Load Webpage" >
    </Button>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="100"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/genre"
            android:entries="@array/genre_list"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/sort"
            android:entries="@array/sort_list"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/page"
            android:entries="@array/page_list"
            android:layout_weight="0.20"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/previousPage"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Previous Page" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nextPage"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Next Page" >
        </Button>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RelativeLayout` to control the position of `ListView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/readWebpage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Load Webpage" >
    </Button>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/readWebpage"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/genre"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:entries="@array/genre_list" />
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/sort"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:entries="@array/sort_list" />
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/page"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.20"
            android:entries="@array/page_list" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/previousPage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Previous Page" >
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nextPage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Next Page" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This helped me to see how to setup my code correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set the layout_weight of the buttons to 0 and then set the layout_weight of the listview to 1.  The layout_weight is use to allocate extra space, so the buttons will keep their 40dip height and the listview will expand to take up the remaining space

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:maxLines="100"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/readWebpage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Load Webpage" >
    </Button>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="100"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/genre"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:entries="@array/genre_list" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/sort"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:entries="@array/sort_list" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/page"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.20"
            android:entries="@array/page_list" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/previousPage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="Previous Page" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/nextPage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="Next Page" >
            </Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```